# How to get data from URL using smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I want to get data from this URL:

```
plblog/frontent/all-post.php?plcn=&plpn=2
```

I need to get the value of "**plpn**" which is **2**

I am using {smarty}

I tried

```
{$idcat = $_GET['plpn']}
```

But it does not work!

Please help!

Comment: This should not be the task of your template.

Comment: Though the design factors could be in question, does [this reference](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl) help for what you are trying to do?